# Getting azure blob metadata key values using azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, data-fabric

Is there a easy way to access azure blob metadata key values through data factory or any other easier solution when loading the data in to azure dataware house on fabric.

I tried using getmetadata component and looks like that is not doing the job

Answer (score 0):

To get the metadata of the blob you need to use the [Rest API Get Blob Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-metadata?tabs=shared-access-signatures) It will return you all the User-defined Metadata.

- To execute it you need to use web activity and setup connection as below.

```
base url : https://storageacc name.blob.core.windows.net/container/blob?comp=metadata&<SAS Token>
Authentication : Anonymous
```

[image]

- Select the newly created connection in web activity and method as **GET**.
  [image]

**Output:**

**In Response Headers you will get `X-ms-meta-<key> : <value>`**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [Web activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) with the URL being your blob address:

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| URL | https://[your-account-name].blob.core.windows.net/[your-container-name]/[your-blob-name] |
| Method | GET |
| Authentication | System Assigned Managed Identity |
| Resource | https://storage.azure.com |
| Headers | x-ms-version : 2020-06-12 |

An example of how to configure it:

[image: Web activity]

This will return the content in an `ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders` object, in the form of:

[image: Web activity return values]

As you can see, all metadata keys are prefixed with `x-ms-meta-`.  You can then access the metadata keys, eg in a [Set Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-set-variable-activity) activity:

```
@activity('Web1').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders['x-ms-meta-mymetadatakey']
```

I also did a `split` by double-quote (") and then a Filter activity so I could loop through them with a For Each loop.

```
Filter items: @split(string(activity('Web1').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders),'"')

Filter condition: @startswith(item(), 'x-ms-meta-')
```